# updating non-null values of a column via function

Tags: pandas

I would like to replace the non-null values of column `myCol`. The new values are returned by a unary function `myFunc`.

This is my solution

```
t['myCol']= t.loc[t['myCol'].notna(), 'myCol'].apply(myFunc)
```

Is there a simpler solution in which I don't need to repeat literal `myCol` three times?

For the comparison, this would be the solution in [q/kdb+](https://code.kx.com/v2/) if `myFunc` accepts vector as input:

```
t: update myFunc myCol from t where not null myCol
```

and if `myFunc` tolerates scalar only then

```
t: update myFunc each myCol from t where not null myCol
```

Answer (score 3):

#### `pandas.DataFrame.mask`

The first argument is the condition and the second argument is what to do at those places where the condition is `True`.  And, `mask` has an `inplace` argument to make the call succinct.

```
t.mask(pd.notna, myFunc, inplace=True)  # For whole DataFrame
```

Or

```
t.myCol.mask(pd.notna, myFunc, inplace=True)  # For just `myCol`
```

Or

```
t.myCol.mask(pd.notna, lambda s: s.apply(myFunc), inplace=True)
```

---

#### MCVE

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2, np.nan], B=[3, np.nan, 4]))

df.mask(pd.notna, lambda x: x * 10, inplace=True)
df

      A     B
0  10.0  30.0
1  20.0   NaN
2   NaN  40.0
```

This works for a specific column with `pandas.Series.mask` just as well

```
df.A.mask(pd.notna, lambda x: x - 5, inplace=True)
df

      A     B
0   5.0  30.0
1  15.0   NaN
2   NaN  40.0
```

Comment: This works well if your function accepts Series, i.e. it uses vector operations only. My function accepts scalar, e.g. `lambda x: str(hashlib.sha1(str.encode(x)).hexdigest())`

Comment: I saw your comment prior and updated my post.  See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update - it looks better. I observed that `myFunc` is evoked even for np.nan elements, which is quite strange. I assume that the ouput is thrown away. If you cannot modify `myFunc` and it does not tolerate floats (type of np.nan), then you need to create a wrapper that performs a type check :( In my case the function requires a string as input.

Comment: For comparison, my (less elegant) solution calls `myFunc` only to elements that are not np.nan, therefore, no protection is required.